# Apostrophe or comma in an alert box (confirmation box) not working

Tags: javascript, php, confirm

I am working on a php script for karaoke events.
The script displays the songs available in the database after submitting a searchterm.
The user can then click on the songtitle to add the song to a queue.
The "queue" is a database table which is going to be displayed on another page.

But before the function ads the song to the queue, I want to display a confirmation box which should repeat the songtitle and artist.

Here´s my code

```
echo "<a href=\"index.php?action=queue&id=$showid\"
onclick=\"return confirm('Do you really want to sing $showtitle by
$showartist?')\">$showtitle</a>";
```

It works in general, but the problem now is that there are quite a few songs in the database which have a "comma" or "apostrophe" in the song title.

In this case the confirmation box just doesn´t show up and the song is added to the queue immediately. As the songtitle which is displayed in the box is always a different one, depending in which song the user clicks, I need to replace or escape these special characters in general in some way.

Is this possible?

Comment: PHP that outputs HTML that outputs Javascript is a recipe for pain.

Answer (score 1):

Need to escape the quotes

try

```
$showtitle = addslashes($showtitle);
```

Best suggestion is to not use inline javascript

Comment: Thanks for your hint, I tried that but without any change in behaviour.
I will try to change my code and solve this in another way (just started with php, mysql etc)....thanks again...